# Unity Serialization Error with List of Derivative Class

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, serialization, abstract-class

For some reason that I do not know, adding `[SerializeReference]` for my list of an abstract class that I've made causes errors inside Unity's code that I can't see inside of. This might be some Unity bug, or my fault for not using serialization correctly.

**Edit:**
I have discovered a condition of the error. It happens when you *LOOK AT* the serialized list in the Unity Editor Inspector window. If you don't actively open the Serialized list inside the inspector, the error doesn't happen. But just looking at it doesn't cause the error, but when you *manipulate* the list it does.

**The main list:** Mainly used for storing data, List is reflected in another script and is being manipulated there.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SingleSpellManager 
{ 
    [SerializeReference]
    public List<ModifierClass> OnCast_Modifier = new List<ModifierClass>();
    //[SerializeReference] do this one later
    //public List<ModifierClass> OnHit_Modifier = new List<ModifierClass>();
}
```

**The Classes:**

```
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class ModifierClass 
{ // stuff inside, unrelated to the error 
}

// derivatives
[System.Serializable]
public class Projectile : ModifierClass
{ // stuff inside, unrelated to the error 
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Delay : ModifierClass
{ // stuff inside, unrelated to the error 
}
```

**Reflect list in another script:** I'm reflecting the list to make it easier to work with between two different scripts. Kinda have a feeling this is the cause of the error.

```
public class SCC_GUI_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Load_ModifierList_OnCast()
    {   // clear the panel
        foreach (Transform child in ModifierList_OnCast_Space.transform) 
        {GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);}

        // reflect list
        OnCast_ModifierList = SelectedSpell.OnCast_Modifier;

        // load the panel
        foreach(ModifierClass CC in OnCast_ModifierList)
        {
            GameObject newElm = Instantiate(Modifier_elm, ModifierList_OnCast_Space.transform);
            newElm.GetComponent<ModifierElm_UI>().SCC_GUI_Manager_scpt = this;
            newElm.GetComponent<ModifierElm_UI>().Modifier = CC;
        }
    }
}
```

**Manipulation of the list.** this is not the only manipulation that can happen, but this is the one that consistently triggers the error.

```
public class SCC_GUI_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{   // moving the modifier to new index inside list     
    public void Move(int oldIndex, int newIndex, int onWhatTrigger)
    {
        if(onWhatTrigger == 0)
        {   // move it
            ModifierClass item = OnCast_ModifierList[oldIndex];
            OnCast_ModifierList.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
            OnCast_ModifierList.Insert(newIndex, item);
        }
    }
}
```

**The error:** inside Unity Editor's Console

```
NullReferenceException: SerializedObject of SerializedProperty has been Disposed.
UnityEditor.SerializedProperty.FindPropertyRelativeInternal (System.String propertyPath) (at <88872b21b1e746a7ad699974a2be8304>:0)
UnityEditor.SerializedProperty.FindPropertyRelative (System.String relativePropertyPath) (at <88872b21b1e746a7ad699974a2be8304>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.BindPropertyRelative (UnityEngine.UIElements.IBindable field, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <68890c016c7a40d7ab0d5ba9aecf643f>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.BindTree (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <68890c016c7a40d7ab0d5ba9aecf643f>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.ContinueBinding (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <68890c016c7a40d7ab0d5ba9aecf643f>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.DefaultSerializedObjectBindingImplementation+BindingRequest.Bind (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element) (at <68890c016c7a40d7ab0d5ba9aecf643f>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualTreeBindingsUpdater.Update () (at <6350d5f72ec34638985fbaab06c4c559>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualTreeUpdater.UpdateVisualTreePhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualTreeUpdatePhase phase) (at <6350d5f72ec34638985fbaab06c4c559>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.Panel.UpdateBindings () (at <6350d5f72ec34638985fbaab06c4c559>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.UpdateSchedulers () (at <6350d5f72ec34638985fbaab06c4c559>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration.UpdateSchedulers () (at <6350d5f72ec34638985fbaab06c4c559>:0)
UnityEditor.RetainedMode.UpdateSchedulers () (at <68890c016c7a40d7ab0d5ba9aecf643f>:0)
```

Comment: Reading up on `[SerializeReference]`, it sounds completely antithetical to both managed environments and serialization. That attribute makes no sense. I wouldn't say that *you* are using serialization incorrectly so much as *Unity* is. It looks like the object has been either moved or garbage-collected and the reference to the object is no longer available.

Comment: so what to do now? @madreflection

Comment: There is not enough information in this post. How you populating this list? How are you handling the saving of the object? Let me remind that if you're changing serialized fields form Editor script, you need to at least SetDirty your object. From what you've described for me it seems like you've changed the size of a serialized collection, but didn't recorded the actual objects. A tip: try to save the object correctly and explore how it is serialized (the asset or the object on scene) - open the asset/scene with text editor and go through what was saved, it is very human-readable.

Comment: Can you show where and how you're using `SingleSpellManager`? Your code here is valid and works fine if copy-pasted into an empty project.  Also, do you have any plugins installed that modify the inspector?

Comment: @Xander I've edited the post for more info including more codes relating to the list. I have a feeling that the Shallow Copy  (the list reflecting) here: `OnCast_ModifierList = SelectedSpell.OnCast_Modifier;`, is the one's causing unity to act like this. No plugins installed @Foggzie

Comment: 1. What is the Unity version you're using? 2. Is there a custom Editor script that is trying to read/manipulate given list? The stack trace says that there is UIElements part of inspector thet is trying to present serialized list. Try to debug the editor script that draws the inspector to figure out how the list is manipulated outside of the script. But in general I advise to encapsulate the list and provide only access methods to the interface of a containing class.